# Search string value inside an array of objects inside an object of the jsonb column- TypeORM and Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

the problem I am facing is as follows:

**Search value:** 'cooking'

**JSON object:**:

```
data: {
   skills: {
      items: [ { name: 'cooking' }, ... ]
   }
}
```

**Expected result:** Should find all the "skill items" that contain 'cooking' inside their name, using **TypeORM** and **Nest.js.**

The current code does not support search on the backend, and I should implement this. I want to use TypeORM features, rather than handling it with JavaScript.

**Current code:** (returns data based on the userId)

```
const allItems = this.dataRepository.find({ where: [{ user: { id: userId } }] })
```

I investigated the PostgreSQL documentation regarding the [PostgreSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) and even though I understand how to create a raw SQL query, I am struggling to convert this to the TypeORM equivalent.

**Note:** I researched many StackOverflow issues before creating this question, but do inform me If I missed the right one. I will be glad to investigate.

Can you help me figure out the way to query this with TypeORM?

**UPDATE**

Let's consider the simple raw query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.data->'skills' @> '{"items":[{ "name": "cooking"}]}';
```

This query will provide the result for any item within the items array that will match **exact** name - in this case, "cooking".

That's totally fine, and it can be executed as a raw request but it is certainly not easy to maintain in the future, nor to use pattern matching and wildcards (I couldn't find a solution to do that, If you know how to do it please share!). But, this solution is good enough when you have to work on the exact matches. I'll keep this question updated with the new findings.

Comment: When you create a raw SQL query do not convert but run it natively in TypeORM. What could be the reason to use a query builder to build a query that you have already built?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Yes. I thought about it, and it is not a problem to actually build the SQL query and just run it natively, my point was to actually use TypeORM features, such as "find()..where(..)". I got the legacy project, and no one has ever used raw SQL queries, just wanted to make sure I stay consistent. I'll have to try a few more things before introducing the raw SQL query into the project. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

use Like in Where clause:

```
servicePoint = await this.servicePointAddressRepository.find({
                where: [{ ...isActive, name: Like("%"+key+"%"), serviceExecutive:{id: userId} },
                        { ...isActive, servicePointId: Like("%"+key+"%")},
                        { ...isActive, branchCode: Like("%"+key+"%")},
            ],
                skip: (page - 1) * limit,
                take: limit,
                order: { updatedAt: "DESC" },
                relations:["serviceExecutive","address"]
              });
```

This may help you! I'm matching with key here.

Comment: This looks like it could work, would you be able to provide an example of your JSON object, just to use it as a reference when analyzing this code? Thanks!